# The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i am getting an error "The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call." on my VB project.
The error just pops out while running the project for debugging.

I already tried to reboot my computer and re-install MySql.

I am using MySql and VS 2013. I don't have any idea on what to do.

Thanks.

this is the error i get.."The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call."
my program in VB automatically connects to the database. So every time i run it for debugging i should connect to the database and my datagrid should have it's contents.

It's actually working before, but i think my computer F***** up and messes up the project.

this is the code..

Public Sub testconnection()
        Try

```
        Dim conn As String = "Database=ngp;data source=localhost; user id= root; password=admin"
        Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(conn)

        connection.Open()
        connection.Close()
        MsgBox("Database connection has been established.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
```

Comment: could you show me the snippet that cause the error

Comment: I don't have any idea on how to help too. until you provide more info.

Comment: your question lacks lots of needed info. just guessing:try this one http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70676

Comment: i added the code that connects to the database.

Comment: @sharky , I already checked that one. However, I am using VS 2013 so i don't know if it still applies..thanks